# API to update node pool count

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

To save the cost is there any API so that I can directly hit from the postman to decrease & increase the node pool count of the GKE cluster on GCP.

Also, the same API that I can use to automate it through pubsub function.

I was trying the below API but it has auth and API keys, Can anyone help, please.

HTTP request
POST [https://container.googleapis.com/v1/{name=projects/*/locations/*/clusters/*/nodePools/*}:setSize](https://container.googleapis.com/v1/%7Bname=projects/*/locations/*/clusters/*/nodePools/*%7D:setSize)

Comment: Have you played with [gcp api explorer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.zones.clusters.nodePools/setSize?apix=true)

Answer (score 0):

take a look into this documentation:

[Kubernetes Engine API](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest)

it contains what seems to be the functionality you are looking for among many others:

**REST Resource: v1beta1.projects.locations.clusters.nodePools**\

**Methods**\

`create`    POST /v1beta1/{parent=projects/*/locations/*/clusters/*}/nodePools
Creates a node pool for a cluster.

`delete`    DELETE /v1beta1/{name=projects/*/locations/*/clusters/*/nodePools/*}
Deletes a node pool from a cluster.

`get`   GET /v1beta1/{name=projects/*/locations/*/clusters/*/nodePools/*}
Retrieves the requested node pool.

`list`  GET /v1beta1/{parent=projects/*/locations/*/clusters/*}/nodePools
Lists the node pools for a cluster.